# Base Internalization without storyboard in XCode 5.0

Tags: ios, translation, xcode5

I prefer not to work with Storyboard, so my projects start from an empty project, then in the appDelegate I write code like this:

```
MyViewController *VC = [[MyViewController alloc]init];
self.window.rootViewController = VC;
```

This intro just to tell you that if I try to activate Base Internationalization and I load the controller in that way I obtain just an empty controller. The xib seems not to be loaded.

Let's say that I want just to setup my project to be multi-language in the next future. So I don't add further languages, I keep only English.

These are the steps that I do to activate the Base Internat.

1. Selecting the xib file and pushing "Localize"
2. Localize it for the only Language available, English
3. From "Project" -> tab "info" I select "Use base Internationalization", selecting the only xib available.
4. Back to the xib, I activate the localizable string for English language (at the moment in the "Localization Box" of the xib I see "base" and "english". Eventually I add a Label to the xib.. just to be sure that the strings file will be created correctly.

Now, if I launch the App.... the xib isn't correctly loaded! 
I hate this situation because it would be great to have this project setup for future translations... but it seems to work only if I work with a Storyboard.

Do you have some suggestions or have you experienced something similar with your projects?

Comment: My experience is that Apple is really gearing their development towards storyboards.  You should consider giving in and using them on a new project.  I was really hesitant to do so, but I've really happy with them.

Comment: @HalR thanks for your comment. This is exactly what I thought... at this point I have probably to learn how to use Storyboard :) I don't want to go off topic, but: Do you find any problems working with Storyboard instead of creating your single xib?

Comment: I haven't had problems--My current project has 22 view controller, and is really robust.  My friend said that its hard to deal with them with source control and multiple developers, and my storyboard is pushing the limit of ease to follow.  So I've heard suggested that  you use multiple storyboards.